# Extract text from JSON in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am trying to extract a specific value from a JSON column in SQL Server. Unfortunately I have read several posts on this topic but still cannot figure out how to translate their solutions to what I need. I am looking to extract "foo testing" but simply do not understand how to get at this with a nested JSON. Can someone please advise?

The structure of the JSON column is:

```
{
    "values": [
        {
            "id": "x01",
            "status": "STATUS1",
            "subStatus": "SubStatus1",
            "values": [
                {
                    "key": "dropdown",
                    "value": "",
                    "optionType": null
                }
            ]
        },
        ...
        {
            "id": "x03",
            "status": "STATUS3",
            "subStatus": "SubStatus3",
            "values": [
                {
                    "key": "dropdown",
                    "value": "",
                    "optionType": null
                },
                {
                    "key": "textInput",
                    "value": null,
                    "optionType": null
                },
                {
                    "key": "checkbox1",
                    "value": true,
                    "optionType": null
                },
                {
                    "key": "textInput2",
                    "value": "foo testing",
                    "optionType": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: please tag your dbms

Comment: What defines the location of `"foo testing"` in the JSON? Are you searching by array index, or perhaps by `id` and `key`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement depends on the structure of the parsed JSON, in your case you need to use two nested `OPENJSON()` calls and additinal `APPLY` operators. Note, that you need to use `AS JSON` in a `"values"` column definition to specify that the referenced property contains an inner JSON array and the type of that column must be `nvarchar(max)`.

Test table:

```
DECLARE @json varchar(max) = '
{
    "values": [
        {
            "id": "x01",
            "status": "STATUS1",
            "subStatus": "SubStatus1",
            "values": [
                {"key": "dropdown", "value": "", "optionType": null}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "x03",
            "status": "STATUS3",
            "subStatus": "SubStatus3",
            "values": [
                {"key": "dropdown", "value": "", "optionType": null},
                {"key": "textInput", "value": null, "optionType": null},
                {"key": "checkbox1", "value": true, "optionType": null},
                {"key": "textInput2", "value": "foo testing", "optionType": null}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
'
SELECT JsonColumn
INTO JsonTable
FROM (VALUES (@json)) v (JsonColumn)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT j1.[id], j2.[key], j2.[value] -- or add all columns
FROM JsonTable t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.JsonColumn, '$.values') WITH (
   [id] varchar(3) '$.id',
   [status] varchar(30) '$.status',
   [subStatus] varchar(30) '$.subStatus',
   [values] nvarchar(max) '$.values' AS JSON
) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[values], '$') WITH (
   [key] varchar(50) '$.key',
   [value] varchar(50) '$.value',
   [optionType] varchar(50) '$.optionType'
) j2
```

Result:

```
id  key        value
---------------------------
x01 dropdown   
x03 dropdown   
x03 textInput  
x03 checkbox1  true
x03 textInput2 foo testing
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following query

```
;with summery as(
   SELECT * 
   FROM OPENJSON((SELECT value FROM OPENJSON(@json)))
   WITH (
    id NVARCHAR(50) 'strict $.id',
    status NVARCHAR(50) '$.status',
    subStatus NVARCHAR(50) '$.subStatus',
    [values] NVARCHAR(max) '$.values' AS JSON
  )
) 
select id,status,subStatus,[key],value,optionType from summery 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(summery.[values])
   WITH (
      [key] NVARCHAR(50) '$.key',
      [value] NVARCHAR(50) '$.value',
      [optionType] NVARCHAR(50) '$.optionType'
);
```

*demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ef34206281bec08d5f284cdc13e4d835)*